Sitecore XMC external editing host WAF rules
Wanted to ask the Sitecore community on how they have setup an external Editing Host for XMC and the WAF rules for it.
I have followed
https://anbrue.net/2023/08/23/sitecore-xm-cloud-external-editing-host-and-firewall/
but the Azure WAF anomaly scoring blocks XMC requests using rule 949110 which cannot be disabled.
Also, looks like XMC doesn't append the query string parameter with all the media requests. It seems to add it for the main request /api/editing/render.
How secure is the internal Editing Host?
Is it publicly available, or does XMC add some restrictions so that its only accessible from XMC Pages or Experience Editor?
At the moment I am short of ideas to secure our external Editing Host and any help or direction would be appreciated.
